# ClassNotFoundException on ServletContainer when configuring Jersey in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

When trying to configure jax rs in intellij I get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1945)
```

My webconfig looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.umbrella.server.api</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I manually downloaded the entire jersey pack from the [official jersey website](https://jersey.github.io/download.html). Which should contain all the dependencies.

The weird thing is that whenever I create a class that derives from the ServletContainer it doesn't give any errors.

Comment: You don't use Maven, do you?

Comment: No, I didn't use Maven.

Comment: What Jersey version have you downloaded?

Comment: I downloaded Jersey 2.27, that implements JAX-RS 2.1 API API

Comment: Where did you put the jar files?

Comment: I added it to web/WEB-INF/libs/api

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184172/discussion-between-jan-wiebe-and-eugen-covaci).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anwser with the help of Eugen Covaci.

In the Intellij project settings there is a tab called problems. When clicking solve on the problems listed there it started working again.

Another issue was that the jar files were located in web/WEB_INF/libs/api instead of the correct folder (web/WEB_INF/lib)